# Mutating XML in Clojure

Tags: xml, clojure

Clojures clojure.xml/parse, clojure.zip/xml-zip and clojure.contrib.zip-filter.xml/xml-> are excellent tools for pulling values out of xml, but what if I want to change the xml (the result of clojure.zip/xml-zip) based on what I learn from xml-> "queries" and write the result back out as xml?

I would have expected that (clojure.contrib.prxml/prxml (clojure.xml/parse xml-content)) spit back xml, but that is not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Actually, for emitting XML, it's best to use `clojure.contrib.lazy-xml/emit`, because `clojure.xml/emit` is currently likely to break things! See my comment below.

*(Leaving this answer here for now as a warning.)*

---

If I understand correctly, the main thrust of the question has to do with turning the (possibly mutated) XML representation back into XML text?

If so, have a look at `clojure.xml/emit` and `clojure.xml/emit-element`:

```
user> (with-out-str (xml/emit {:tag :foo :attrs {:bar "quux"}}))
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n<foo bar='quux'/>\n"
```

(`with-out-str` captures printed output and wraps it up as a string; for some reason `xml/emit` prints the xml, so it comes in handy here. You'll want to use `emit-element` if `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` is not what you want.)

Comment: For the benefit of future readers: Apparently this is very limited in its usability, as `clojure.xml/emit` currently takes a very naive approach to its job and e.g. neglects to encode stuff as XML entities... Use `clojure.contrib.lazy-xml/emit` instead. Also see my answer to the follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463129/roundtripping-xml-in-clojure-using-clojure-xml-parse-and-clojure-xml-emit/2463768#2463768

Answer (score 7):

You can use the xml-zip library to "mutate" XML just like you would any other of Clojure's immutable structures. It has a full set of "mutating" functions: [(api)](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.zip-api.html)

They all return an entire "modified" zipper. You can then go to the top of that zipper, and user xml/emit to print the XML.